# Is there a generic class to write structured Text Files?

Tags: .net, text-files

I have several projects that need to write structured Textfiles, some with fixed size fields, other delimited by characters.

Is there a .net class that could be used for that?

I know there is a "Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser" that is useful for reading textfiles, i am actually searching for a ""Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldWriter"

Related: [Alternatives for enhanced reading and parsing text files using .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34182/reading-text-files-using-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.com/)

> The FileHelpers easy to use .NET
>   library written in C# to read/write
>   data from fixed length or delimited
>   files or streams.

Comment: @Burnsys Yes that's the one. I see it was also suggesting in your related question. Is there any reason not to use this library?