# C# 2.0 Fastest way to parse Excel spreadsheet

Tags: c#, excel, interop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reading Excel files from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15828/reading-excel-files-from-c-sharp)

What is the fastest way to read large sets of data from excel from Csharp. Example code would be great . .

Answer (score 2):

In our desktop environment, I have reached the best mix between performance, flexibility and stability by using Excel via COM.

Access to Excel is always via the same thread.

I use late-binding (in VB.Net) to make my app version independent.

The rest of the application is developed in C#, only this part and some other small parts are in VB, because they are easier in VB.Net.

```
Dim workBook As Object = GetObject(fileName)
Dim workSheet As Object = workBook.WorkSheets.Item(WorkSheetNr)
Dim range As Object = workSheet.Cells.Item(1, 1)

Dim range2 As Object = range.CurrentRegion

Dim rrow As Integer = range2.Row ' For XL97, first convert to integer. XL97 will generate an error ' 
Dim rcolumn As Integer = range2.Column

Dim top As Object = workSheet.Cells.Item(rrow, rcolumn)
Dim bottom As Object = top.Offset(range2.Rows.Count - 1, range2.Columns.Count - 1)

range = workSheet.Range(top, bottom)

Dim values As Object(,)

values = range.Value
```

Here you have a 2-dimensional array containing the values from Excel. The last statement gets the data from Excel to .Net.

Since the limits on the size of a Excel sheet, these cannot get very large, so memory should not be a problem.

We have done some tests on performance, on multiple systems. It is optimized to create as few as possible (out-of-process) COM calls.

This way was the one that has given us the best performance, specially since the data is directly in an array, and access to this data is faster as going through a dataset.

Slow in this solution is starting Excel. But if you need to process multiple files, right after each other, the cost of starting Excel is made only once.

Also I would not use this solution in a server environment.

Comment: He wants fast for large sets of data, have you compared the speed of the COM based operation to a datasource based method? I would also be interested to know if your solution can reasonably keep up with the datasource method. (I would rather read and not hold a large datatable in memory)

Answer (score 1):

```
public class ExcelHeaderValues
{ 

        public static string CUSIP = "CUSIP";
        public static string ORIG = "ORIG";
        public static string PRICE = "PRICE";
        public static int COLUMNCOUNT = 3;
}

public class ExcelParser
    {
        private ArrayList collOutput = null;

        string sSheetName = String.Empty;
        string[] strValidColumn;
        int validRowCnt = 0;
        string sColumnPositions = String.Empty;

        OleDbCommand ExcelCommand;
        OleDbDataAdapter ExcelAdapter;
        OleDbConnection ExcelConnection = null;
        DataSet dsSheet = null;
        string path = string.Empty;
        string identifier = string.Empty;


        public ExcelParser()
        {
            collOutput = new ArrayList();
        }      

        public void Extract()
        {
            bool headermatch = false;
            string strCusip = string.Empty, strOrig = string.Empty, strPrice = string.Empty, strData = string.Empty;
            string strCusipPos = string.Empty, strPricePos = string.Empty, strOrigPos = string.Empty;

            string strColumnHeader = String.Empty;
            int reqColcount = 0;
            string[] strTemp;
            bool bTemp = false;
            bool validRow = false;


            DataTable schemaTable = GetSchemaTable();

            validRowCnt = 0;
            foreach (DataRow dr in schemaTable.Rows)
            {
                if (dsSheet != null)
                {
                    dsSheet.Reset();
                    dsSheet = null;
                }
                strCusipPos = string.Empty;
                strOrigPos = string.Empty;
                strPricePos = string.Empty;

                if (isValidSheet(dr))
                {
                    sColumnPositions = string.Empty;
                    validRowCnt = 0;
                    foreach (DataRow dataRow in dsSheet.Tables[0].Rows)
                    {
                        sColumnPositions = string.Empty;
                        if (headermatch == false)
                        {
                            sColumnPositions = string.Empty;
                            foreach (DataColumn column in dsSheet.Tables[0].Columns)
                            {
                                strColumnHeader = dataRow[column.ColumnName].ToString().ToUpper().Trim();
                                strColumnHeader = strColumnHeader.ToUpper();
                                if (strColumnHeader == ExcelHeaderValues.ORIG.ToUpper() || strColumnHeader == ExcelHeaderValues.CUSIP.ToUpper() || strColumnHeader == ExcelHeaderValues.PRICE.ToUpper())
                                {
                                    bTemp = true;
                                    validRow = true;
                                    reqColcount = ExcelHeaderValues.COLUMNCOUNT;
                                }
                                if (bTemp)
                                {
                                    bTemp = false;
                                    sColumnPositions += column.ColumnName + "^" + strColumnHeader + ";";
                                }
                            }
                            strValidColumn = sColumnPositions.Trim().Split(';');
                            if (validRow == true && reqColcount == strValidColumn.Length - 1)
                            {
                                headermatch = true;
                                break;
                            }
                            validRowCnt++;
                        }
                    }
                    if (headermatch == true)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            if (dsSheet.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                            {
                                if (strValidColumn.Length > 0)
                                {
                                    for (int i = 0; i < strValidColumn.Length - 1; i++)
                                    {
                                        if (strValidColumn[i].ToUpper().Contains("CUSIP"))
                                        {
                                            strTemp = strValidColumn[i].ToString().Split('^');
                                            strCusipPos = strTemp[0].ToString();
                                            strTemp = null;
                                        }

                                        if (strValidColumn[i].ToUpper().Contains("PRICE"))
                                        {
                                            strTemp = strValidColumn[i].ToString().Split('^');
                                            strPricePos = strTemp[0].ToString();
                                            strTemp = null;
                                        }

                                        if (strValidColumn[i].ToUpper().Contains("ORIG"))
                                        {
                                            strTemp = strValidColumn[i].ToString().Split('^');
                                            strOrigPos = strTemp[0].ToString();
                                            strTemp = null;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                for (int iData = validRowCnt; iData < dsSheet.Tables[0].Rows.Count; iData++)
                                {
                                    if (strCusipPos.Trim() != "")
                                        strCusip = dsSheet.Tables[0].Rows[iData][strCusipPos].ToString().Trim();
                                    if (strOrigPos.Trim() != "")
                                        strOrig = dsSheet.Tables[0].Rows[iData][strOrigPos].ToString().Trim();
                                    if (strPricePos.Trim() != "")
                                        strPrice = dsSheet.Tables[0].Rows[iData][strPricePos].ToString().Trim().ToUpper();

                                    strData = "";
                                    if (strCusip.Length == 9 && strCusip != "" && strPrice != "" && strOrig != "" && !strPrice.ToUpper().Contains("SOLD"))
                                        strData = strCusip + "|" + Convert.ToDouble(strOrig) * 1000000 + "|" + strPrice + "|||||";
                                    if (strData != null && strData != "")
                                        collOutput.Add(strData);

                                    strCusip = string.Empty;
                                    strOrig = string.Empty;
                                    strPrice = string.Empty;
                                    strData = string.Empty;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            throw ex;
                        }
                    }
                    headermatch = false;
                    sColumnPositions = string.Empty;
                    strColumnHeader = string.Empty;
                }
            }
        }

        private bool isValidSheet(DataRow dr)
        {
            bool isValidSheet = false;
            sSheetName = dr[2].ToString().ToUpper();

            if (!(sSheetName.Contains("$_")) && !(sSheetName.Contains("$'_")) && (!sSheetName.Contains("Print_Titles".ToUpper())) && (dr[3].ToString() == "TABLE" && ((!sSheetName.Contains("Print_Area".ToUpper())))) && !(sSheetName.ToUpper() == "DLOFFERLOOKUP"))
            {
                if (sSheetName.Trim().ToUpper() != "Disclaimer$".ToUpper() && sSheetName.Trim().ToUpper() != "Summary$".ToUpper() && sSheetName.Trim().ToUpper() != "FORMULAS$" )
                {
                    string sQry = string.Empty;        
                    sQry = "SELECT * FROM [" + sSheetName + "]";
                    ExcelCommand = new OleDbCommand(sQry, ExcelConnection);
                    dsSheet = new DataSet();
                    ExcelAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(ExcelCommand);
                    isValidSheet = false;
                    try
                    {
                         ExcelAdapter.Fill(dsSheet, sSheetName);
                        isValidSheet = true;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        isValidSheet = false;
                        throw new Exception(ex.Message.ToString());
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        ExcelAdapter = null;
                        ExcelCommand = null;
                    }
                }
            }           
            return isValidSheet;
        }



        private DataTable GetSchemaTable()
        {
            DataTable dt = null;
            string connectionString = String.Empty;
            connectionString = GetConnectionString();
            ExcelConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
            try
            {
                ExcelConnection.Open();
                dt = ExcelConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            return dt;
        }



        private string GetConnectionString()
        {
            string connStr = String.Empty;
            try
            {

                if (path.ToLower().Contains(".xlsx"))
                {
                    connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + "Data Source='" + path + "';" + "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1;'";
                }
                else if (path.ToLower().Contains(".xlsm"))
                {
                    connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + "Data Source='" + path + "';" + "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=No;IMEX=1;'";

                }
                else if (path.ToLower().Contains(".xls"))
                {
 connStr = "provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='" + path + "';Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1;'";

                }
                else
                {connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + "Data Source='" + path + "';" + "Extended Properties='HTML Import;IMEX=1;HDR=No;'";

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            return connStr;
        }

}
```