# Excel & Microsoft.Office.Interop

Tags: excel

I want to use the Microsoft.Office.Interop to read an Excel file from a web page.
Do I need to have Office installed on my web server?
I am not doing any manipulation to the excel file, just reading it in and storing the values to another page.  I have no issues when I run on my local machine but I have Excel installed on my local machine.  Anyone that knows this answer I would greatly appreciate your input.
Thanks 
JD

Answer (score 2):

Using Interop requires that you have Office installed on the server. For websites, I would generally recommend using something like the open-source [NPOI](http://www.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?ProjectName=npoi) project. However, if all you ever want to do is read, consider using ADO.NET (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15828/reading-excel-files-from-c) for more info).

Answer (score 0):

I would add that if your using Excel as a datasource the ADO approach is much faster and requires less overhead.  It restricts you to excel sheets that are pretty much structured as flat tables.  But if I can use that method (all restrictions considered) I prefer it.

Ernie