# Upload Excel File and display in Grid in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel, upload

I need to export the Users List from excel to my asp.net mvc(C#) application.

> The Excel should have an header like **First Name Last Name Email**,...
>     
> and its values like                                                   John          Smith           john@gmail.com,
>                                                                                  David         Beckam       david@gmail.com,

Need to validate the values before storing it to my database and show it in the grid of next page.

Is there any easy way to do it, like a plugin?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that it would be best, in this case, to use ADO.NET.

A few articles on how to do this in order to read values from an Excel Worksheet:

(1) [Reading and Writing Excel Spreadsheets Using ADO.NET C# DbProviderFactory (David Hayden)](http://elemirac.wordpress.com/2010/03/12/read-write-excel-ado/)

(2) [Import Excel File to DataSet (CodeProject)](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/ExcelToDataset.aspx)

(3) [Tips for reading Excel spreadsheets using ADO.NET (Lab49)](http://blog.lab49.com/archives/196)

(4) [Reading Excel files from C# (Stack Overflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15828/reading-excel-files-from-c)

I think that this should get you to where you need to go.

-- Mike

Comment: Updated the previously-broken link.