# Integrating ASP.NET Page With MS Excel as DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, vba

I want to create a ASP.NET application which will fetch and store data from excel. For eg. currently i have automated excel reports using VBA and Macros, and user have to oem all the excels to get the data/charts/tables. All i want to let them open an asp.net application and from there only they can fetch reports, edit the reports and save the data and my excel will be used as DB. Please suggest is it's possible and if possible.

Comment: web is multi user environment, and excel is not well suited for concurrent access, so I would avoid this solution.

Comment: @Giedrius I understand your concern, but still was thinking to avoid my users multiple excels and let them do all at a place in case possible

Answer (score 0):

As far as extracting the excel spreadsheet data you can take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553417/upload-excel-file-and-display-in-grid-in-asp-net-mvc) to see a couple alternatives.

As far as getting around the concurrent access issue, you can store the excel information in some form of multi-user concurrent persistant storage - could be on disk or in-memory store (sql server, couchbase, memcache, etc...) and then access information from that store on user request.

Comment: i think you are missing a link under the `this post` :P