# Interfacing Between C# And Excel?

Tags: c#, excel

I am using C# interop to call a macro from C#.

This works fine.

However I am passing in an argument which the macro populates in the event of an error.

```
app.Run(macroName, errrObj, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, ........);
```

Is there any way to get C# to actually read the new value that the arg is set too?

Am I doing this wrongly??

The macro simply does this

```
Public sub abc(errorObj as variant)
errorObj = "HELLO WORLD"
End Sub
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15828/reading-excel-files-from-c and about fifteen million others.

Comment: I think he wants to use the return value from excel macro.

Comment: Yes - Its the return value from Excel I am after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, according to the IDL, this parameter is `In`. There is no way to read it from C#. Alternatively, try to use a global variable:

```
Dim errorObject as String

Function GetError As String
    GetError = errorObject
EndFunction

Funcion func(...)
   ...
   errorObject = ....
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks - Do you have a link to the IDL which confirms this please?