# Reading and parsing Excel files in C#

Tags: c#, excel, parsing

What is the best way/library to read Excel 2003 and 2007 files using C#? I need to do some heavy parsing.

Comment: See this question; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15828/reading-excel-files-from-c

Comment: What do you mean by "heavy parsing"? Can you provide some example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [SmartXLS for .Net](http://www.smartxls.com),it support most features of excel(cell formatting,Charts,formulas,pivot tables etc),and can read/write both the excel97-2003 xls format and the excel2007 openxml format.

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to parse the file, or deal with the contents?

For parsing the file, you'd better hope it's in [Open Office XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML) format, because the previous binary version is not documented at all.

If you just need to deal with the *contents*, use the [Office Interop libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the MS Office interop assemblies (see [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20100618063307/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/excel/archive/2006/06/19/636534.aspx)) to access Excel files from .NET applications.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by trying to use [ADO.NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316934). 
If that doesn't work, I used [xlsio](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/reporting-edition/xlsio) by Syncfusion.

Answer (score 1):

If the data is in some kind of table format I'd suggest to try using `OleDbConnection` and treating the Excel sheet as another data connection. Otherwise Interop is ok if it's not on a server or anything like that.

Answer (score -1):

There are a number of 3rd party tools you can use. I would avoid using the Interop libraries as they can be pretty slow. I have used Aspose.Cells before and it works pretty well. It does cost some money though.