# Visual Studio data-driven tests

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2010, mstest

I'm using a TextContext property to access the current row in an Excel file. The test is repeated for all rows.
Is it possible to access all rows in a single step? Rows are related, hence for me one sheet should be a complete run.

Edit:
I add some code as requested:

```
int result = this.TextContext.Rows[0]["GlobalResult"];
foreach(var row in this.TestContext.Rows.Skip(1))
{
    componentToTest.Eval(Convert.ToInt32(row["A"]), Convert.ToInt32(row["B"]));
}
Assert.AreEqual(result, componentToTest.Result);
```

And the file would appear like this:

GlobalResult, A, B
100, null, null
null, 1, 5
null, 3, 6
...
and so on

Thank you very much

Comment: It might be helpful if you could post some code?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using data driven tests, why don't you just read the Excel file and iterate through the rows? Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15828/reading-excel-files-from-c) SO question on how to read an Excel file's contents. You can then iterate through the rows in a test without having to use MSTest data driven attributes.

Cheers.
Jas.