# Is there any Open source Library to generate and edit .xls and .ppt file?

Tags: c#, office-interop

My task is to extract information from ppt file and compare with another ppt file. I have to use windows platform so i used excel and powerpoint's COM object.

After developing and testing the code in my computer when i exported the file into another computer it just failed. I started to debug in that file, and surprisingly debug was successful from first to last but as soon as click on the executable it fails.

I am totally *ucked up now cause inspite of updating excel dll files into those computers  (which will serve the com support) it's not working. In every pc it gives different error message. I don't wanna work COM object anymore. It *ucks.

**Can anyone suggest me any open source alternative in which i can read and extract information from Excel and Powerpoint files (both 2003 and 2007 format) ???**

My preferred language is c# ........I got an paid solution (aspose) but i don't wanna go for that.

Any help will be appreciated. Just suggest me how can i deal with office files assuming ms office is not installed in my computer.

Comment: you seem to be blaming COM, for your lack of knowledge of it. But, yes, it can suck if you don't understand the versioning/binding subtleties

Comment: This has been asked many a times...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15828/reading-excel-files-from-c

Comment: [Aspose](http://www.aspose.com/) really is an excellent solution if you come up short on the free stuff.

Comment: @ mitch: It's not fault for lack of knowledge. It's because of shitty msdn documentation. I followed that and it was never warned about versioning/binding there. Please provide me some link on solving this (if you believe it's solvable "easily")

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tcf61s1(VS.80).aspx

Comment: @ astander: When i wrote this question, this question wasn't shown in suggestion. Please be sure that, before asking this question i searched for this and asked only when i failed to find what i am asking.

Comment: @ mitch: From the link, for c# tab: "This language is not supported or no code example is available.".........Please recheck your link, there is no information here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/) works well for Excel; I only know to use the built in, MS object library for PPT files.

Comment: It doesn't support powerpoint 2003, but i need ppt support also. So it's not gonna work for me :-(