# c# read excel file

Tags: c#, excel

I'm trying to read the cells into an excel file without using ole db, 'cause I can't create the data into the excel *(the excel file comes from my client and I can't modify...)*

how can I do?
thanks

Comment: read the cells from an excel file into C#, or write to an excel file from C#? Also, but excel do you mean .xls format or is it simple .csv ?

Comment: what?  can you elaborate as to why you would need to modify the file if you're just trying to read the contents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try looking at the answer of this question - hopefully that will help you..

[Reading Excel files from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15828/reading-excel-files-from-c)

Answer (score 1):

Don't understand your question. But maybe [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/) can help.

Answer (score 0):

Use interop library for excel. you should define a `workbook` and a `worksheet` then a `range` and read all cells in that range so easy...

Comment: this requires every user of your software to have Excel installed

Comment: @KBoek: is this restricted in the question?