# C# application to import excel file content into a text file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have excel file with following columns

```
Field1 Field2 Field3, Field4
===============================
123 4   abcd    efghi
456 5   aabb    ffjjk
789 7   ccdd    ababa
```

I would like to write a c# console application that 
would read the excel file and create text file with the 
following output

```
Field1 Field2 Field3, Field4
===============================
123 4   ab  hi
456 5   aa  jk
789 7   cc  ba
```

in my console application, I should be able to specify per column in excel file, the start and, end columns.

How would I write the application from start to finish?

Comment: "from start to finish" sounds like you want others to do your work.
I would strongly suggest pointing to a specific problem.

Comment: This "question" should be broken down into all the sub-parts of the problem that are giving you trouble. Do you know how to access data from an excel file? Do you know how to get user input in a console application? Do you know how to iterate, transform, and output data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way of doing this is to query to spread sheet

```
string strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;data source=C:\\Inetpub\\wwwroot\\CS\\HostData.xls;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
OleDbConnection objConn = new OleDbConnection(strConn);

string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [A1:B439]";
OleDbCommand objCmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, objConn);

objConn.Open();
dgReadHosts.DataSource = objCmd.ExecuteReader();
dgReadHosts.DataBind();
objConn.Close();
```

i grabbed this example from here: http://forums.asp.net/t/1097496.aspx
another good source is to search SO :P   [Reading Excel files from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15828/reading-excel-files-from-c)

Lastly i think you'll like this one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd920313.aspx

 it includes an example using linq AND and example of outputting the spreadsheet to the consol

Answer (score 2):

You can just use Excel Automation to get out the data and then just write it to a file using the standard `System.IO` classes.

See here for details: [How to automate Microsoft Excel from Microsoft Visual C#.NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302084)

If you manage to retrieve all the values for one row into some kind of array or list, you could then use `String.Join` to convert that into a tab separated string and then just write one line at a time to the file.

To only get certain parts of the values for some columns, you might be able to use `String.Substring`.

You might also be able to use `OleDB` to read out all the data, since it seems to be in a tabular format, which could be faster and avoid the dependency on having Excel installed.