# I am looking for the information about Excel embed into the WinForm. (under C# 4.0)

Tags: c#, winforms, excel, browser

I am looking for the information about Excel embed into the WinForm.

I am developing under C# 4.0, WinForm now.

My question is
How could I excel embed into the form?
How could I open excel file in the WinForm apps?

As I know, when the control,  WebBrowser(or AxSHDocVw.AxWebBrowser) is using, it was working before under ealier .NET runtime.
But I don't know why the way is not working anymore.
For security or whatever.

So I want to know have any better way to embed or open Excel file in the win form?
I hope you could let me know useful information for that.

Please, help me, I will waiting for the information.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend a component called SpreadSheetGear (http://www.spreadsheetgear.com).  It's pricy, but works very well out of the box and can save you considerable headache and the need to have excel installed on the client.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out: [How to Integrate Excel in a Windows Form](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/Embedding_Excel.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this links help you.

[Reading Excel files from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15828/reading-excel-files-from-c)

http://www.davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/05/26/2973.aspx