# Read a cell (or range of cells) directly from an open workbook in Excel using C#?

Tags: c#, excel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reading Excel files from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15828/reading-excel-files-from-c)

Is there a way to read a cell (or range of cells) directly from an open Excel or OpenOffice worksheet? I have a graphing app that can read .csv files but would like to read straight from Excel to make it more interactive.

Comment: I did search but no other question had an answer that worked for me

Comment: Also, the workbook that is open will be in memory, so I don't think there is any way to access through .NET (if that's what you're getting at).  It is an interesting question though.