# Add Description From Excel File to Columns description  in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a DB (in SQL Server 2008 SP3) include many tables and each tables have a lot of columns, in other hand I have an Excel file include description for any of my DB's columns (In SQL Server Management Studio when you want create a table, in design mode, for each column in property window there is a description field), So I am interesting in add this(Excel) description to description of columns in DB (of course not by hand and one by one), does any one have any idea about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knock up some VBA to iterate through the Excel data, calling the database for each table/column.

The SQL Server stored procedure you want (if I understand correctly) is [sp_addextendedproperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180047.aspx) to add comments about objects in SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

You can get help from some references given below: please have a look over there, thanks

a. [Reading and Writing Excel](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/excel_using_oledb.aspx)

b. [Reading Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15828/reading-excel-files-from-c-sharp) and then save to your DB