# How to label the columns (add data description) in SQL?

Tags: sql, r, sqlite, label

I want to add data description (information about what each column represents, and some additional information) to my SQL database. It is similar to the `label data`/`label variable` command in Stata, and the `var.labels` attribute of dataframes in R (requires the `readstata13` package, can be accessed via `varlabel(df)`).

Here's an example of what I wanted (taken from the Stata manual):

[image]

There is a variable label on the variable `id` to explain what is stored in that column.

I want to know, is this possible in standard SQL (I am using SQLite via the `RSQLite` package)?

For example, if I want to read/write the labels of a dataframe in R, I can do

```
library("readstata13")

# df is a dataframe with three columns

# Get labels of all columns
varlabel(df)

# Get label of one specific column
varlabel(df, var.name = "variable_name")

# Set label for all columns
varlabel(df) <- c("label1", "label2", "label3")

# Set label for one specific column
varlabel(df, var.name = "variable_name") <- "This is a label"
```

I do find this question on Stack Overflow: [Add Description From Excel File to Columns description  in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463419/add-description-from-excel-file-to-columns-description-in-sql), which uses the `sp_addextendedproperty`, but it seems to be an SQL Server-only feature (which, unfortunately, is not a possible option for me).

Comment: I can't get the code highlighting to use R syntax (putting "R" after the opening ``` doesn't work), so sorry for the awful code highlighting :(

Comment: *"add data description ... to my SQL database"* to me sounds like `UPDATE TABLE mytable ADD COLUMN label text` (https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-alter-table/).