# How to populate listbox from excel using C#

Tags: winforms, excel, import-from-excel

I have an windows application. I browse for the file and select the excel file using OpenFileDialog control. The excel file contains email id's in column A. I want to populate the list-box with excel file column values. Office 2003 is installed on my machine. Can somebody Please help me out?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading Excel files from C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15828/reading-excel-files-from-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer: [Reading Excel files from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15828/reading-excel-files-from-c-sharp)

To connect to an excel file you need the appropriate connection string:

```
string connString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=<YourExcelPath>;
Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;\"";
```

After use the OleDb classes to query the information from the file:

```
string selectCmd = "SELECT * FROM <SheetName>";

using(OleDbConnection excelConn = new OleDbConnection(connString))
{
    excelConn.Open(); 
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(selectCmd, excelConn);
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);

    DataTable sheetInfo = new DataTable();
    dataAdapter.Fill(sheetInfo);

    //Do something with the data.
    Bind your control with this datatable here
}
```

So you need to replace "YourExcelPath" with the path of your excel file..