# C# Read Excel workbook

Tags: c#, arrays, excel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reading Excel files from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15828/reading-excel-files-from-c-sharp)

I have seen similar post, but mine is more trivial than the others I have seen.

I need to do read the default worksheet from an excel file, and get the first  3 columns of data and import them into my app as in a List

```
List<MyObj> obj = new List<MyObj>();.

 obj.col1 = ...
 obj.col2 = ...
 obj.col3 = ...
```

There are no headings in the document just data.
Also would be good to have a solution that works for both formats (XLS,XLSX) but if not possible than thats ok.

Also is it different code for XLSX and XLS ?

Im using .NET 2 but if need I could use  c# 4

```
col1data  |  col2data | col3data
col1data  |  col2data | col3data
col1data  |  col2data | col3data
col1data  |  col2data | col3data
...
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15828/reading-excel-files-from-c-sharp

Comment: thanks it looks ok, but Im not sure what do I put in place of ..adapter.Fill(ds, "anyNameHere");

Comment: adapter is going to be an instance of the DataAdapter class. It is what is used to represent the data-source in memory for the purpose of reading/writing. Basically in that example the data adapter is used to fill a DataSet object with the data from the Excel document.

Comment: ok thanks, I think I have it.