# Select only one column values from Excel

Tags: c#, excel, com-interop

So I'm using C# to read through an Excel (.xlsm) file, everything is fine... Until all I want to do is read one column. That's all I want to do, some sample code here:

```
Worksheet sheet = (Worksheet)workBookIn.Sheets[sheetName];
Range r =
    sheet.get_range("B2", sheet.Cells.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell));
Array vals = pitch.Cells.Value;
```

Also, if anyone could suggest a more elegant approach to the latter part of the code (i.e. processing the range of Excel values), please feel free to comment.

Comment: Is your code not working as-is?

Comment: It works, but not the way in which I want it; i.e. it is selecting beyond the B column.

Comment: The answer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/16051/16391 addresses what you need here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Worksheet sheet = (Worksheet)workBookIn.Sheets[sheetName];
Range r =
    sheet.get_range("B2", "B" + sheet.Cells.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell).Row);
Array vals = pitch.Cells.Value;
```