# Importing spreadsheet using C# in WinRT platform and manipulating the data

Tags: c#, excel, windows-runtime

I am developing an application which primarily imports spreadsheet reads the data and manipulates it.
I was googling all day, unable to find a way to read data from excel files.
It would be great if I could get some help to do the required.

Information :
I am developing **Windows Store app using C#/XAML.**

Reference libs/apps which read excel :

http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/SpreadNET/

http://www.greatwindowsapps.com/app/tile-charts

Comment: I just googled "C# Excel read" and found this in the top results - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15828/reading-excel-files-from-c-sharp

Comment: whether winRT supports ADO.Net approach ?

Comment: Have you tried? You have all the tools available to you. Read the link and see. If not then update your question with what you have tried.

Comment: I have tried ExcelDataReader . Source is incompatible for WinRT and i was not able to refer the dll in my project. I am using vs2012 Express which supports only WinRT apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted the same the question in the MSDN Blog

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/4fce4765-2d05-4a2b-8d0a-6219e87f3307

Code provided by **VT.CrazyAppy**  works fine for reading & parsing simple spread sheet file.
The code snippet is static , I am working on it to make it more generic.will post the code 
once I done with that.

Note : The code will provide a mechanism to read a simple spread sheet file and return them as  K,V pair.
You can modify it to suit your need.

Answer (score 0):

If you look for a free open source solution, I used in several projects [exceldatareader from codeplex](http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/) lib, very simple and easy to use.

It depends only by SharpZipLib, I think that you have only to recompile both projects as portable libs to make it work on WinRT.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with `.xlsx` files there's always [Open XML SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124) which you can [get from NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/) as well. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc850837%28v=office.14%29.aspx)'s a bunch of tutorials to get you started. Unfortunately the really nice wrapper library [ClosedXML](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/) doesn't work with Windows Store apps.

There's also a commercial component available, [XlsIO from Syncfusion](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/winrt/controls), which you could try out. I don't have any first hand experience with it.