# Simple Example of VSTO Excel using a worksheet as a datasource

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, excel, vsto, excel-2010

I think I'm running into a case of "the easiest answers are the hardest ones to find" and I haven't come across any searches that give this to me in a straightforward way. This is for **Excel 2010** and **VS 2010** within an existing VSTO (C#) project.

I have an Excel worksheet that contains 4 columns of data that I would like to use as a source for a DataGridView. Can someone please provide C# code snippets for (1) getting the data from a particular worksheet and populating a custom object with it? (2) binding the object (like an IEnumerable list) to a Datagridview and (3) some snippets for the update and delete functionality that would be inherent to the grid and feed back to the source worksheet.

I know I'm asking for a lot here, but so much of the VSTO information seems to be dis-jointed and not always easy to find. Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at this?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15828/reading-excel-files-from-c-sharp

Comment: I can see how this is not clear in my question: I am working on an Excel Workbook as my project. So I'm trying to read the data *within* Excel itself. I'm assuming I need a ListObject example at some point but I'm not positive.

Comment: Conceptually VSTO just enables you to access the Excel object model from managed code running within the Excel process.  So you should orient your search to the Excel object model rather than VSTO - most examples are in VBA but easy to port to managed C#.  You're right that a ListObject is probably the easiest way to go.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Edit:** Great, I just noticed that I missed a big part of your question, getting updates and deletes back to the worksheet. I have absolutely no idea if that is possible but I think that makes my solution worthless. I'll leave it here anyway, maybe it can help in any way.

---

Why do you need VSTO? As far as I know VSTO is used for Office Add-Ins. But since you want to show the data in a DataGridView I assume that you have a WinForms application that should just access a workbook. In this case you can simply open the workbook by using Office Interop. Just add a reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel to your project and add a `using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;` statement.

MSDN reference documentation for Excel Interop can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms262200%28v=office.14%29.aspx

I'll give you the Excel part, maybe someone else can do the rest.

First, open Excel and the workbook:

```
Application app = new Application();
// Optional, but recommended if the user shouldn't see Excel.
app.Visible = false;
app.ScreenUpdating = false;
// AddToMru parameter is optional, but recommended in automation scenarios.
Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Open(filepath, AddToMru: false);
```

Then somehow get the correct worksheet. You have a few possiblities:

```
// Active sheet (should be the one which was active the last time the workbook was saved).
Worksheet sheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
// First sheet (notice that the first is actually 1 and not 0).
Worksheet sheet = workbook.Worksheets[1];
// Specific sheet.
// Caution: Default sheet names differ for different localized versions of Excel.
Worksheet sheet = workbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"];
```

Then get the correct range. You didn't specify how you know where the needed data is, so I'll assume it is in fixed columns.

```
// If you also know the row count.
Range range = sheet.Range["A1", "D20"];
// If you want to get all rows until the last one that has some data.
Range lastUsedCell = sheet.Cells.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell);
string columnName = "D" + lastUsedCell.Row;
Range range = sheet.Range["A1", columnName];
```

Get the values:

```
// Possible types of the return value:
// If a single cell is in the range: Different types depending on the cell content
// (string, DateTime, double, ...)
// If multiple cells are in the range: Two dimensional array that exactly represents
// the range from Excel and also has different types in its elements depending on the
// value of the Excel cell (should always be that one in your case)
object[,] values = range.Value;
```

That two dimensional object array can then be used as a data source for your DataGridView. I haven't used WinForms for years so I don't know if you can bind it directly or first need to get the data into some specific format.

Finally close Excel again:

```
workbook.Close(SaveChanges: false);
workbook = null;
app.Quit();
app = null;
// Yes, we really want to call those two methods twice to make sure all
// COM objects AND all RCWs are collected.
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

Correctly closing Excel after using Interop is a task itself because you have to make sure that all references to COM objects have been released. The easiest way I have found to do this is to do all the work except opening and closing Excel and the workbook (so my first and last code block) in a seperate method. This ensures that all COM objects used in that method are out of scope when `Quit` is called.

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE:**

I replaced my previous method with newer code for faster approach. `System.Array` is quite efficient and faster way to read and bind data to the excel. You can download the demo from [this link](https://sites.google.com/site/blogshippo/style/ExcelToDGV.zip).

---

I have developed VSTO application in Excel 2003 Workbook. There is no big differences in terms of syntax,so you can use it in 2007 / 2010 with no efforts.

[image]

I didn't know which event you will be using to open the window showing data so i am assuming that you will be using.

```
SheetFollowHyperlink
```

I am going to use Static workbook object declared in Showdata.cs. Here's the code for your `Thisworkbook.cs`

```
 private void ThisWorkbook_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            ShowData._WORKBOOK = this;
        }
private void ThisWorkbook_SheetFollowHyperlink(object Sh, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Hyperlink Target)
        {
            System.Data.DataTable dTable =  GenerateDatatable();
            showData sh = new showData(dTable);
            sh.Show(); // You can also use ShowDialog()
        }
```

I have added a Link on the current sheet and it will pop up the window with a datagridview.

```
         private System.Data.DataTable GenerateDatatable()
    {
        Range oRng = null;
        // It takes the current activesheet from the workbook. You can always pass any sheet as an argument

        Worksheet ws = this.ActiveSheet as Worksheet;

        // set this value using your own function to read last used column, There are simple function to find last used column
        int col = 4;
        // set this value using your own function to read last used row, There are simple function to find last used rows
        int row = 5;
```

//lets assume its 4 and 5 returned by method
            string strRange = "A1";
            string andRange = "D5";

```
        System.Array arr = (System.Array)ws.get_Range(strRange, andRange).get_Value(Type.Missing);
        System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
        for (int cnt = 1;
            cnt <= col; cnt++)
            dt.Columns.Add(cnt.Chr(), typeof(string));
        for (int i = 1; i <= row; i++)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            for (int j = 1; j <= col; j++)
            {
                dr[j - 1] = arr.GetValue(i, j).ToString();
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

Here's the form which will allow user to display and edit values. I have added **extension method**s and  Chr() to convert numerical into respective alphabets which will come handy.

```
public partial class ShowData : Form
    {
        //use static workbook object to access Worksheets
        public static ThisWorkbook _WORKBOOK;

        public ShowData(System.Data.DataTable dt)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // binding value to datagrid
            this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }

        private void RefreshExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Worksheet ws = ShowData._WORKBOOK.ActiveSheet as Worksheet;
            System.Data.DataTable dTable = dataGridView1.DataSource as System.Data.DataTable;

            // Write values back to Excel sheet
            // you can pass any worksheet of your choice in ws
            WriteToExcel(dTable,ws);
        }

       private void WriteToExcel(System.Data.DataTable dTable,Worksheet ws)
    {
        int col = dTable.Columns.Count; ; 
        int row = dTable.Rows.Count;

        string strRange = "A1";
        string andRange = "D5";

        System.Array arr = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(object),5,4);
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
            {
                try
                {
                    arr.SetValue(dTable.Rows[i][j].ToString(), i, j);
                }
                catch { }
            }

        }
        ws.get_Range(strRange, andRange).Value2 = arr;
        this.Close();
    }
    public static class ExtensionMethods
    {
        static string alphabets = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        public static string Chr(this int p_intByte)
        {

            if (p_intByte > 0 && p_intByte <= 26)
            {
                return alphabets[p_intByte - 1].ToString();
            }
            else if (p_intByte > 26 && p_intByte <= 700)
            {
                int firstChrIndx = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor((p_intByte - 1) / 26.0));
                int scndIndx = p_intByte % 26;
                if (scndIndx == 0) scndIndx = 26;
                return alphabets[firstChrIndx - 1].ToString() + alphabets[scndIndx - 1].ToString();
            }

            return "NA";
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

this is one of the most ugly codes I've written but it will work as a proof of concept :)
I've created an example workbook like that

```
Column1     Column2     Column3     Column4
------------------------------------------------------
Data-1-1    Data-2-1    Data-3-1    Data-4-1
Data-1-2    Data-2-2    Data-3-2    Data-4-2
....
```

Excel file contains exactly 50 lines, this explains the hard-coded range selectors.
After writing that part of code rest is easy, just create a form, add a dataviewgrid, create a data source for `MyExcelData`, create an instance of `MyExcelData` like `var data = new MyExcelData(pathToExcelFile);` and bind it to grid.

Code is ugly, and has many assumptions but it implements your requirements. If you open excel and program you can see updates on grid are reflected on excel after cell edited. deleted row is also removed from excel. since I did not know whether you have primary keys of your excel or not, I used row index as ID.

BTW, I'm really bad when it comes to VSTO. so if you know a better way open/edit/save please notify me.

```
public class MyExcelDataObject
{
    private readonly MyExcelData owner;
    private readonly object[,] realData;
    private int RealId;
    public MyExcelDataObject(MyExcelData owner, int index, object[,] realData)
    {
        this.owner = owner;
        this.realData = realData;
        ID = index;
        RealId = index;
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }

    public void DecrementRealId()
    {
        RealId--;
    }

    public string Column1
    {
        get { return (string)realData[RealId, 1]; }
        set
        {
            realData[ID, 1] = value;
            owner.Update(ID);
        }
    }
    public string Column2
    {
        get { return (string)realData[RealId, 2]; }
        set
        {
            realData[ID, 2] = value;
            owner.Update(ID);
        }
    }
    public string Column3
    {
        get { return (string)realData[RealId, 3]; }
        set
        {
            realData[ID, 3] = value;
            owner.Update(ID);
        }
    }
    public string Column4
    {
        get { return (string)realData[RealId, 4]; }
        set
        {
            realData[ID, 4] = value;
            owner.Update(ID);
        }
    }
}

public class MyExcelData : BindingList<MyExcelDataObject>
{
    private Application excel;
    private Workbook wb;
    private Worksheet ws;

    private object[,] values;

    public MyExcelData(string excelFile)
    {
        excel = new ApplicationClass();
        excel.Visible = true;
        wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(excelFile);
        ws = (Worksheet)wb.Sheets[1];

        var range = ws.Range["A2", "D51"];
        values = (object[,])range.Value;

        AllowEdit = true;
        AllowRemove = true;
        AllowEdit = true;

        for (var index = 0; index < 50; index++)
        {
            Add(new MyExcelDataObject(this, index + 1, values));
        }
    }

    public void Update(int index)
    {
        var item = this[index - 1];

        var range = ws.Range["A" + (2 + index - 1), "D" + (2 + index - 1)];
        range.Value = new object[,]
            {
                {item.Column1, item.Column2, item.Column3, item.Column4}
            };
    }

    protected override void RemoveItem(int index)
    {
        var range = ws.Range[string.Format("A{0}:D{0}", (2 + index)), Type.Missing];
        range.Select();
        range.Delete();
        base.RemoveItem(index);

        for (int n = index; n < Count; n++)
        {
            this[n].DecrementRealId();
        }
    }
}
```

PS: I'd like to use lightweight objects but it adds unnecessary complications.

Comment: "this is one of the most ugly codes" -- In addition to Dijkstra, Shakespeare is not too proud, either.

Answer (score 1):

So in the Sheet1_Startup event

```
Excel.Range range1 = this.Range["A1", missing];
var obj = range1.Value2.ToString();
```

You would need to move to the next cell then

```
    range1 = this.Range["A2", missing];
    obj = New list(range1.Value2.ToString());
```

Comment: But those are just single values from single cells. Isn't there a way to treat an entire worksheet and/or range as a dataset?

Comment: Could use this.Range["A1", "A5"] - But then you are into a list. I don't know how to get it to DS.. Sorry

Comment: @JimBeam: Please check my answer to find out the way to read and write entire range instead of reading and writing every cell one by one.