# Read Excel files and get data from the header and two tables separately

Tags: javascript, excel, xlsx

I have an Excel file which has a big header at first and then two tables below. I tried to read it and get the details using `js-xlsx` but can't separate the data. I need to separately get some data from the header like the van number and dates. Then I need to get the data from the two tables below. Different files have different amounts of products in their tables. Here is a [sample](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51654769/sample.xlsx).

Please help me to get these data out.

Comment: Please be more specific, what do you need to extract exactly and to where. Could you provide a sample of the expected outcome. Need to show also another sample with more lines to identify constants that can be used to extract the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use Microsoft tooling? Visual Studio with VS Tools for Office (VSTO) is very powerful and will allow you to read/manipulate worksheets and cells. (Simple reads and a lot more here: [Simple Example of VSTO Excel using a worksheet as a datasource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16926275/simple-example-of-vsto-excel-using-a-worksheet-as-a-datasource))