# How to read .xls/.csv document using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.SpreadsheetDocument class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, openxml

How to read .xls/.csv document using `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.SpreadsheetDocument` class?

Can read `.xlsx` file perfectly. But having `FileFormatException` in this line when xls file is given.

```
_spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(FileStream, false);
```

Comment: XLSX **is** an Office Open XML format file, while XLS is a binary Office file. No wonder you can't open the latter with the OpenXML `SpreadsheetDocument` class, it just isn't possible...

Comment: Thanks for the knowledge Patryk. It helped.

Answer (score 1):

Open XML only process office 2007 and upper files .docx, .xlsx and .pptx.

And it is not compatible for office 97-2003 documents like .doc, .xls and .ppt.
So you should try something else.

Look at this one: [Reading Excel files from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15828/reading-excel-files-from-c-sharp)

It may help!

**Update:**

One of the useful answers from above link is this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> props = new Dictionary<string, string>();
props["Provider"] = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0";
props["Data Source"] = repFile;
props["Extended Properties"] = "Excel 8.0";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> prop in props)
{
    sb.Append(prop.Key);
    sb.Append('=');
    sb.Append(prop.Value);
    sb.Append(';');
}
string properties = sb.ToString();

using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(properties))
{
    conn.Open();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    string columns = String.Join(",", columnNames.ToArray());
    using (OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(
        "SELECT " + columns + " FROM [" + worksheet + "$]", conn))
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable(tableName);
        da.Fill(dt);
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add more details to your answer. If the link you've provided gets broken in the future, this answer will become useless.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use Jet or some other driver to read the contents of an xls file, as it is not XML.  Additionally, you may want to consider using something like Linq to Excel to query the contents, it works great.