# reading columns from excel sheet into predefined variable

Tags: c#, excel

I have two columns in excel sheet. 1st columns describes the values while 2nd column consist of corresponding values of different type(int, float hex, string). I want to read 2nd column into predefined variable and convert it into byte.
For example

> 1st column    2nd column
>
> vehicle no.   234566(int)
>
> name          alex(string)
>
> validation   0x34239032(hex)

thus I want to read

> int veh_no. = 234566
>
> string name = alex
>
> string valid = 34239032

what will be most efficient method to read it from excel sheet?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Reading excel files with c# has been discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15828/reading-excel-files-from-c-sharp) on stackoverflow.