# How to open excel file and rename excel worksheet?

Tags: c#, excel

Ok, I've search all the other questions regarding this topic but have not yet found a good answer. I need to read an excel file and rename my excel worksheet programmatically. I'm using 2007 excel. Any help? Any Tip?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading Excel files from C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15828/reading-excel-files-from-c-sharp)

Comment: You can use [Excel Interop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, I'd use a free library such as [EPPlus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/) for this. I think it is much cleaner and easier to use then interop.

Something like this:

```
FileInfo finfo = new FileInfo(@"C:\Temp\Book1.xlsx");
using (var excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(finfo))
{
    ExcelWorksheet ws = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"];
    ws.Name = "NewWorksheet Name";
    excelPackage.Save();
}
```

Comment: what namespace or reference do i need to add?

Comment: I did that already, but I'm getting red line under ..= new ExcelPackage

Comment: You need to first install EPPlus via Nuget then you can use `using OfficeOpenXml;` but, if its installed if you just place the cursor inside the `ExcelPackage()` word then hold down ctrl and hit . then Visual Studio should give you that option.

Comment: anyway to autosize column?

Answer (score 1):

```
Worksheet oSheet = (Worksheet)oWB.Worksheets["TheSheetYouWant"];
oSheet.Name = "NewName";
```

Comment: @NewKidOnTheBlock reread the question you've badly put together. This answers "I need to rename my excel worksheet programmatically."

Comment: re check again @Pierre-LucPineault

Comment: @NewKidOnTheBlock Indeed, if you edit the question _after_ an answer, it will get outdated. Instead of changing your requirements, how about you read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and reformat it nicely with all the required info.