# How to load/read excel data into asp.net 5 using OpenXML

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I am trying to import values from excel into asp.net 5. I have done this previously using c# and in windows application utilizing EPPlus. I am very new to the asp environment and having hard time doing this basic operation. I was able to import "DocumentFormat.OpenXml": "2.5.0" into the json file. 
Basically what I want to do is Open up excel, Load data, feed it to list, do bunch operations and display the values back to the user. if someone can help with the getting the excel portion I would appreciate it.

My attempt:

```
System.IO.FileStream _stream = new System.IO.FileStream(path, System.IO.FileMode.Open);

SpreadsheetDocument spreadSheet = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(file,true)
```

I am not sure if I need file streams for this. 
When I try to do this it says:

```
SpreadsheetDocument is not referenced
```

Comment: Check this out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15828/reading-excel-files-from-c-sharp

Comment: I found this resource using which I still have issue using the reference https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ff478410.aspx

Comment: I solved the problem by adding the windows base to the references