# How to run the Selenium _Keyword Data Driven in c#?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, data-driven-tests

Am try to run Keyword Data Driven , unable to get the action Keyword item from excel Ex(Save, Send Keys),how i get the keyword from excel and run visual studio C# ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to utilize the libraries to read from excel.  Once you have access to it that way you should be able to pull in your content to perform actions on.

[reading-excel-files-from-c-sharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15828/reading-excel-files-from-c-sharp)