# How to read excel file using C#

Tags: c#, excel, uitableview, filereader

I have tried this code but it doesn't work:

```
private void Load_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "Excel Workbook|*.xls", ValidateNames = true })
    {
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
             System.IO.FileStream fs = File.Open(ofd.FileName, System.IO.FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
             ExcelDataReader.IExcelDataReader reader = ExcelDataReader.ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(fs);
             reader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;
             result = reader.AsDataSet();
             cboSheet.Items.Clear();

             foreach (DataTable dt in result.Tables)
                 cboSheet.Items.Add(dt.TableName);

             reader.Close();    
         }
     }
}
```

I can't seem to run this code because the `IsFirstRowAsColumnNames` and `AsDataSet` has red underlines.

I found the code here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7X3fTnuII7c

Comment: you can use answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15828/reading-excel-files-from-c-sharp?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

From the [instructions for the library](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader):

> Install the `ExcelDataReader.DataSet` extension package to use the `AsDataSet()` method to populate a `System.Data.DataSet`.

So you need an [additional library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExcelDataReader.DataSet/) here.

The `IsFirstRowAsColumnNames` property doesn't exist at all, perhaps it's a legacy item that has been removed. Instead, it looks like you need to pass in configuration to the `AsDataSet` method, for example:

```
ds = reader.AsDataSet(new ExcelDataSetConfiguration()
{
    ConfigureDataTable = (tableReader) => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration()
    {
        UseHeaderRow = true
    }
});
```

Comment: I have already installed this. Still it's not working. I'm a beginner in C# programming . I kinda stuck again XD

Comment: Read the instructions for the library.

Comment: Currently reading it. i hope i could find the key.