# Worksheet to .net Dataset

Tags: c#, excel, database, dataset

I am very much a novice when it comes to C#, but I am trying to get Worksheets from an Excel Spreadsheet into a dataset using Visual Studios. 
I have a DLL called InfExcelExtension for which i've screenshot here. I just need a good start off position really as I don't know which Visual Studio Project to use initially, and roughly where to go from there?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSdRn.png)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSdRn.png)

[image]

Comment: It dosen't matter which type of project you will create - coding is important in here. It can be WinForms app as well as console app. Try `EPPlus` library. It's extremely flexible and easy to use. Download link: [EPPlus on GitHub](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with `InfExcelExtension`.  A quick google doesn't seem to turn much up, so unless you're reliant on this for some reason I'd probably just use something else.

In terms of what sort of project to use, if you only need this to run on standard windows machines then I'd suggest a .Net Framework class library.  This will produce a DLL you can use in a variety of apps.  You can then produce a command line app (console app) or a winforms app (graphical windows app) which uses this - or both...

If the computer on which your program will run HAS excel installed, you can use Interop functionality, see here:
https://coderwall.com/p/app3ya/read-excel-file-in-c

note: this basically loads Excel in a process in the background and allows you to interact with it, hence you need excel.

Alternatively, you can use OLE stuff as detailed here:
[Reading Excel files from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15828/reading-excel-files-from-c-sharp)

Comment: it should be a comment

Comment: InfExcelExtension is a dll I made myself.

Comment: @MaciejS.why?  I've provided links to two different solutions plus some advice about structuring things.  How does that not constitute an attempt at an answer?

Comment: @voot89 That was what I initially thought, but then google did turn up a couple of results mentioning it so I thought maybe it was some obscure library from somewhere.  In which case just put your logic in there and then use that library in whatever type of app suits your needs.

Comment: @voot89 you made it but you don't know how to use it?